# Unable to install py-audio due to installation error

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install py-audio on ubuntu following the guide here:

https://github.com/theintencity/py-audio/blob/master/README.md

I have been able to build correctly, however whenever I try to use py-audio I get the following

**error:**

```
cannot load audiodev.so and audiospeex.so, please set the PYTHONPATH
```

I have tried adding these to my `PYTHONPATH` so that it now looks like this:

```
py-audio:audiospeex:audiodev
```

But I am still getting the same error and don't know how else to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The PYTHONPATH should contain absolute directory names, such as /home/user/python/lib:/home/user/python/extras/lib.  Find the directories that those files exist in and modify your PYTHONPATH appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried changing to the full path which contains the libs and have doubled checked it contains all the .so files, however I still see the error unfortunately

Comment: Can you post your PYTHONPATH?  It should contain the paths to those libraries only, not the libraries themselves (just wanting to make sure)